# Configuring Google OAuth2 Access Token on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, google-oauth

I'm currently facing an issue with OAuth2 access token. Currently, my app periodically uses the google OAuth2 Tokens to get events from my personal google calendar and is able to add new events to the google calendar. However, an exception occured saying that the token expired. After searching through google, I found out that you cannot set the access token to have no expiry date, and using API key wouldn't work as I cannot then add new events to the google calendar(Is this true ?)

I am using the Credentials.from_user_authorized_files and build from the credentials to access the API. It appears that even when I provide no value in the "access_token" field it still works, that must mean that my refresh token was the one needed and it expired. I read up online that for refresh tokens to be permanent, the app needed verification from google, otherwise it will expire in 7 days. I am unsure on how to solve the issue. I generated a new refresh token and it seemed to work. How do I prevent the refresh token from expiring ? Or is this not a problem with the refresh tokens ? Are there any other way I can make this work without having to manually change the refresh token every 7 days ? Thanks in advance !